# Is it possible that a person is unaware of her own realisation?

Tags: moksha

Moksha is the highest state, according to the sanathan dharma, to be realised by any human. Every one is already present in moksha state. It is only the thing that she need to realise that she is in moksha state.

Some people with several kinds of siddhis can **experience** them by seeing and talking with divine beings or by astral travel etc., Such powers are noticeable to the practitioner. It may happen by sudden physical experience that does not happen till that moment in her life.

Is there any sudden, inevitable and experienceable change that happens at the moment when one gets realisation? Or **is there any chance for realisation to happen unnoticingly**?